# AngularJS 2-way binding before API call is complete

Tags: angularjs

I am using a basic API call to get an array of items to display in a table. My table loads perfectly fine, but I noticed that Angular is throwing a bunch of errors telling me that it can't interpolate expressions, etc.

I realized that this is because for the split second between page load and the API call response, Angular is trying to render the table and is obviously getting errors because the array used to populate the table does not exist yet.

Therefore, what is the standard way to get rid of this problem? Should I simply use `ng-If` or `ng-hide` to stop the render until the API call is complete or is there another way to tell angular to "wait" before rendering the DOM.

I was also able to fix this by initializing the array like `$scope.dataArray = []`, but I feel like this is a hassle when dealing with complex JSON objects that have many arrays and objects that need to be initialized.

Can someone please explain the best way to do this?

Comment: I am interested in this as well. Normally, I'd go with `ng-hide` or `ng-cloak` depending on the scenario.

Comment: I tried ng-hide and ng-If and they both still show these errors. So far the only "fix" is to initialize any array that is used in the template to be `[]`.. The only problem is if our page uses 15 different arrays, then we have to initialize all of these onto the `$scope` before the data is retrieved from the server via an API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way this can be handled is using the `resolve` property on the router or state provider.

With `ui-router`'s `$stateProvider` you can do this:

```
.state('mystate', {
    controller: function($scope, data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    },
    resolve: {
        data: ['$http', function($http) {
            return $http.get('/api/get-data');
        }]
    }
})
```

And the promise from the `$http.get()` will be resolved before the controller is instantiated. This works the same way using `ngRoute`.

- $routeProvider (`ngRoute`) docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider
- video showing resolve: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve
- another blog explaining resolve: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The solution you've already come upon yourself is the correct one. Even if you are feeding Angular an empty scope variable or collection, that's all fine with the framework. What it won't accept is a complete null reference.

To avoid sullying your controllers, think about slurping up some some models into a parent controller, and nesting related objects, i.e. `$scope.magic[]`, which contains `$scope.magic.user`, etc.

That's the gospel!